# HelloAndroid not launching on emulator using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-emulator, ddms

I'm running the android SDK 3.0 and trying to debug with the eclipse adt plugin.  My helloAndroid app is sometimes getting updated on the emulator but it never launches.  There are several symptoms:

First, my console shows these messages:

> [2011-03-18 08:05:26 - ddmlib]An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
>   java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Secondly, the logcat view in eclipse contains lots of these messages:

> 03-18 12:13:13.243: INFO/jdwp(387): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping

Third, the DDMS perspective in eclipse is completely blank except for a console view.

I tried reinstalling the ADT and platforms.  I tried setting up the development tools on the emulator target for debugging (Dev Tools>Development Settings> Wait for Debugger).  I tried changing some of the debug configurations (manual/automatic, launch default activity, launch com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid).

I'm currently having some success getting the app to upload, but I need the debugger and DDMS.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the daemon doesnt find the emulator. Try command console and a list disponibles devices

Comment: I tried 'adb devices' and it lists the emulator. Is that what you meant? Also, the app was updated on the emulator.

Comment: Yeah, adb see the devices, so you can see the device on DDMS tab view. It take sometimes a long time to deploy on your emulator. tell me what happens.

Comment: Time is not the issue.  I upgraded to compatible adt/eclipse versions (10.0.1/3.6.2).  I think that if you configure the emulator to save to/start from snapshot snapshot there's some baggage that you're stuck with if you close at an inopportune time.  Somehow this is tied to my problem where I see complaints about a 2nd DDMS.  Deleting and recreating the avd cleans that up.  But I've yet to see the app get launched successfully if launched with the debugger. But if I manually start the app, select the process with DDMS then switch from landscape to profile, (or vice versa) I hit a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I just moved up to ADT 10 and API3.0 in Eclipse (Linux) and it works, but is very slow. I had several debuggerd error messages initially. Have you researched this on the Eclipse side? It seems like an integration issue..

Comment: I agree. BTW I'm running eclipse 3.4.2.  I looked into upgrading just ddms using the eclipse software updates and add-ons tool and it failed with the following dependency issues:

Comment: I'm on 3.5.2, but I don't think that is the issue. It's like anything new.. What OS are you running? I am  on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and all current Java bin/src. I also have a laptop on Win7 set up the same way. I am using svn so I have the same source updates on both machines and the Windows machine has had several library issues and errors. I think it has more to do with your platform than anything else. I have been programming for 15 years and love Linux/Eclipse, it just works.

Comment: It turns out that this was part of the problem by the misfortune of timing, I was running eclipse 3.4.2 and android ADT 10.0.0.  When I went back to review my installation I found this comment in the release notes for ADT 10.0.1: "Fix issue in which ADT 10.0.0 would install on Eclipse 3.4 and lower, even though ADT requires Eclipse 3.5 or higher (as of 10.0.0)."  So the fact that 10.0.0 let me install into eclipse 3.4 was a bug.  I upgraded to 10.0.1 and the DDMS funniness is gone but I still can't start up and debug from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for `android "Ignoring second debugger"` suggests that you're running two DDMS or two ADT plugins (or Eclipse instances). This is preventing the debugger to work.

Comment: I did that but I think ddms may be running in the context of a java vm (or dalvik?).  It doesn't seem to show up as a separate process in windows.  Also, this problem happens immediately, even after I reboot my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Exit all the eclipse instances, close ddms, open command prompt and type adb kill-server
Start the eclipse.

I keep getting these messages in the DDMS console when I connect my Atrix device, however, I ignore them.